# Description environment with line break and no indent in labels but indented body

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, enumitem

I have a description list with a label that does not a fit on one line. I want a line break in the label such that the second line of the label is not indented. I still want the body text to be indented. (To get the body text to start on a new line I use the hack `~\\`—perhaps there is a better solution?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
    \item[
        This is a too long label.
        It would not be if I did not add this sentence.
        I do not want this line to be indented.
    ]~\\
    However, I want the body of the item to be, just as it is.
    \lipsum[1]
    \item[An item with a short label.]~\\
    This looks good.
    \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not right - it produces overfull boxes. However, perhaps somebody else will find it a useful basis for a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\SetLabelAlign{myparleft}{\parbox[t]\textwidth{#1\par\mbox{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}[align=myparleft]
    \item[%
        This is a too long label.
        It would not be if I did not add this sentence.
        I do not want this line to be indented.
    ]
    However, I want the body of the item to be, just as it is.
    \lipsum[1]
    \item[An item with a short label.]
    This looks good.
    \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: description]

Answer (score 0):

Building on cfr's answer, here are two solutions. However it requires manual setting the number of lines in the description.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
    \item[\protect{%
        \parbox[t][2\baselineskip][t]{\textwidth}{%
            This is a too long label.
            It would not be if I did not add this sentence.
            I do not want this line to be indented.
        }
    }]
    Now this looks good,
    with the description wrapped in a parbox.
    \lipsum[75]
    \item[An item with a short label.]~\\
    This looks good.
    \lipsum[66]
    \item[\protect{%
        \begin{minipage}[t][2\baselineskip][t]{\textwidth}
            This is a too long label.
            It would not be if I did not add this sentence.
            I do not want this line to be indented.
        \end{minipage}
    }]
    And this looks good too,
    with the description wrapped in a minipage.
    \lipsum[75]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]